# Ext.Ajax.request : External URL not working?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have this code to replace an ID for a SenchaTouch Web App:

```
function showRates() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://www.google.com',
        success: function(response, opts) {
            Ext.getCmp('card1').update(response.responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

and it works if I change the url to a local file like "ajax.html" for example. Any idea about how can I fix this?

Comment: local file you means that you are trying to ran it offline. Or you are runing applicatiin from a web server. Probabli is a xss security problem. Look the dev console for the error and paste here

Comment: Tried it offline and on a server too. I get the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

You'll want to use JSONP to get content from external servers.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain Ajax calls from JavaScript are not supported by Chrome/Safari browsers. If, you are working for mobile development, try packaging the application with all your source into the WWW/asserts folder and build using Phone gap. It will certainly work.

Hope u getting me. Visit the below links for clear picture.

[cross-domain-ajax-requests-sencha-touch-bits](http://cfmeta.net/2011/08/18/cross-domain-ajax-requests-sencha-touch-bits/)

[Cross-domain-Ext.Ajax-Ext.data.Connection](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?17691-Cross-domain-Ext.Ajax-Ext.data.Connection)